# How to add „From” request header in Firefox-Selenium?

Tags: selenium, firefox, http-headers

I’m looking for a way to add the [“From” request header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/From) to disclose an email address of the requesting user.
I am using Selenium with Firefox, alternatively I can switch to PhantomJS or Chrome.

It could be some preference to set in selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile. I checked Firefox’s about:config documentation, but can’t find any indication how to implement this header. Any help is appreciated especially that it is difficult to google this issue given the name of the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still haven’t found an interface how to do this with Selenium. There is however a workaround with intercepting the request using selenium-wire:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver

def from_request_header_interceptor(request):
    del request.headers['From']
    request.headers['From'] = 'email@example.com'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(**kwargs)
driver.request_interceptor = from_request_header_interceptor
driver.get('https://www.httpbin.org/headers')
```

The httpbin outputs i.a. headers `“From”: “email@example.com”`. Seems to work.